# Discrete Mathmatics Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Here is the question:

$a$ and $b$ are any two integers.  $c$ is any prime.  Prove that if $c$ divides $ab$, then $c$ divides $a$ or $c$ divides $b$ (or both, as in it can divide either or both, i.e. inclusive "or")

Now, I've worked it out myself and I'm not sure if my answer is correct.  If it is, then great! If not, then I'd like some help as to where to start and how to work through it.

Here's my attempt:

Assume $c$ divides $a$ or $c$ divides $b$.  Then, $ab$ is equal to the multiplication of the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$, and $c$ is equal to at least one of the prime factors of $ab$ because $c$ divides $a$ or $c$ divides $b$, and because $c$ is prime.  Hence, $c$ divides $ab$ because $c$ is a prime factor of $ab$.

Comment: Your attempt seems to be proving the wrong direction -- that if $c | a$ or $c | b$, then $c | ab$, while your question is asking you to prove that if $c | ab$, then $c | a$ or $c | b$.

Comment: Your proof is the wrong direction, and works whether $c$ is prime or not (with slight changes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is not correct. You need to prove the statement:

$$c \mid ab \Rightarrow (c\mid a \lor c\mid b)$$

where $x \mid z$ denotes '$x$ divides $z$'. Yet you argue for the converse:

$$(c\mid a \lor c\mid b) \Rightarrow c\mid ab$$

**Hint:** assume $c\mid ab$. Then state the prime factorization of $ab$ in terms of the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$, and try to think of what that entails regarding the divisibility of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I see, so basically reverse the way I explained it?  

Such as this:

Let c|ab. Then, because c is prime, c must be one of the prime factors of the prime factorization of ab in order to divide ab.  ab is the multiplication of the prime factorizations of a and b.  Hence, c|a V c|b because c must be one of the prime factors of either a or b.

Comment: @jonba: that looks fine! Be careful with the use of 'either .. or', though, since it usually denotes an exclusive disjunction (one or the other, not both), and in this case it could also be that $c$ divides both $a$ and $b$. Also, while the proofs are really quite similar in this case, do note that this does not hold generally.

Comment: Thanks Roy, I really appreciate the help! And I see, I understand the difference between exclusive/inclusive, but that helps with wording so thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by others your logic is not correct. You may want to prove it as follows:

Suppose $c$ does not divide $a$. Then due to the fact that $c$ is a prime we get that $\gcd(a,c)=1$. This means there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+cy=1$. Now multiplying throughout by $b$ we get
$$abx+cby=b.$$
Now try showing that left side is divisible by $c$ hence......